# Sequences with PL SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I know how to create a sequence in pl sql.  However, how would I set the values to all have say 3 digits? is there another sql statement to do this when I create a sequence?

so an example would be:

```
000
001
012
003
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, just to be clear, you do not create sequences in PL/SQL.  You can only create sequences in SQL.

Second, if you want a column to store exactly three digits, you would need the data type to be `VARCHAR2` (or some other string type) rather than the more common `NUMBER` since a `NUMBER` by definition does not store leading zeroes.  You can, of course, do that, but it would be unusual.

That said, you can use the "fm009" format mask to generate a string with exactly 3 characters from a numeric sequence (the "fm" bit is required to ensure that you don't get additional spaces-- you could `TRIM` the result of the `TO_CHAR` call as well and dispense with the "fm" bit of the mask).

```
SQL> create table t( col1 varchar2(3) );

Table created.

SQL> create sequence t_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  insert into t
  2    select to_char( t_seq.nextval, 'fm009' )
  3      from dual
  4*  connect by level <= 10
SQL> /

10 rows created.

SQL> select * from t;

COL
---
004
005
006
007
008
009
010
011
012
013

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: wow thank you a lot that is very clear.  however, i am still confused with what fm009 is. why is is 009?  also i dont see where the 3 digit limitation comes from.

Comment: @NoobyBooby - The '009' format mask says "convert the number to a string that is 3 characters long padded with leading 0's".  The 'fm' format mask says "remove the leading space that you would normally reserve so that negative numbers aligned properly in a report".  If you wanted a 4 character string padded with 0's, you'd use 'fm0009'.

Comment: In addition to Justin's excellent post, I would just add this:  Is the data always going to be numeric?  The 3 digits and leading zeros are a display requirement, correct?  If so, I'd argue that you should store the sequence values in a NUMBER datatype in the table, and then use the TO_CHAR() function on output, to format your data appropriately.

Comment: Some caveats: 1) 1000 distinct values are not many, especially since sequences are **not** gap free. 2) Once the sequence `t_seq.nextval`  is above 999, `to_char(t_seq.nextval, 'fm009') will return `####`. 3) You can control the range of the sequence, when created, like so: `create sequence test_seq minvalue 0 maxvalue 999 cycle;` Change `cycle` to `nocycle` to keep the sequence from issuing the same value more than once.

Answer (score 3):

haven't used plsql in a while, but here goes:

given an integer sequence myseq,

```
to_char(myseq.nextval, '009')
```

Comment: @Johhy Cundall - Note that you probably want 'fm009' not just '009'.  Otherwise, Oracle will add an extra leading space so that if you pass in a negative number it has room for the minus sign while maintaining alignment.

Comment: The 009 is the number format model. You can read about that here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the lpad function.

In Oracle/PLSQL, the lpad function pads the left-side of a string with a specific set of characters.

For example:

```
lpad('tech', 7);    would return '   tech'
lpad('tech', 2);    would return 'te'
lpad('tech', 8, '0');   would return '0000tech'
lpad('tech on the net', 15, 'z');   would return 'tech on the net'
lpad('tech on the net', 16, 'z');   would return 'ztech on the net'
```

In your example you would use

```
 lpad('tech', 8, '0');  would return '0000tech'
```

i.e. if the string is less than 8 characters long, add 0s to the start of the string until the string is 8 characters long.

Ref: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lpad.php

Also, to add the 0s to the right you can use the rpad function.